# Must I switch both live and neutral on equipment that is not part of a permanent installation?

Tags: electrical

I've learned that you always switch live in electronics. But today I realized that if you are using equipment that have a regular wall-wart plug that can be inserted either way you have no chance of knowing if the polarity is switched.

This may be an obvious question, but am I right that in equipment that is connected to wall outlets you *have* to switch both neutral and live? Or is there some other clever way around this?

Edit: I should add that I am based in Denmark and live in an older apartment where the wall outlets are not grounded and the plugs that go in them are not polarized.

Comment: Note: In some countries this problem does not arise - even non-earthed plugs are polarised so that live & neutral cannot be swapped by rotating the plug. In a double insulated appliance with no extraneous metal parts it is not so much of an issue.

Comment: Most American wall warts don't alternate the polarity of the secondary when the plug is flipped.   I only included the word "most" because I'm certain there must be an exception but in all honestly I can't think of one.

Comment: I checked. I can reverse the plug and the polarization is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a Class II power supply (wall wart) -- there is no power switch, and the equipment frankly doesn't care which way it's plugged in as it treats the mains as if it were floating and all the user-touchable parts are well-insulated from the mains.

For other equipment, a *polarized plug* is used that can only go into its mating mains receptacle one way around.  This means that the appliance designer can safely assume that the hot wire is hot and the neutral wire is neutral, instead of having to design defensively against being plugged in the other way around.

Since your wall sockets are old, crusty, and not polarized, though -- you'll have to have them replaced by polarized sockets in order to deal with this though, or switch both poles in the appliance.  Check what your national electrical regulations have to say on this.

Comment: What leads me to this question is that I'm repairing a 45 year old electric piano (Wurlitzer) which was absolutely not designed by todays standards in terms of class-compliancy. I've replaced the power socket with a standard IEC-type plug which is polarized but that does nothing if I don't know if the polarization is reversed at the wall outlet.

Comment: @funkylaundry That's a throwback to when 120V electrical was treated as an isolated system.   One easy way to add shock protection is to build an isolation transformer into the appliance. Have your power-of-questionable-polarization feed the primary, and the secondary has no polarization, it is isolated from the power feed.  You'd still want to switch both legs of the primary, however, you wouldn't want to leave the primary humming 24x7.